# JavaScript string split and comparison in IE

Tags: javascript

This is really surprising. I am unable to make a simple string comparison work in IE.

```
"‎6‎/‎17‎/‎2015‎ ‎3‎:‎21‎:‎39‎ ‎PM".split(' ')[2].trim() == "PM"
```

returns **false**!

```
"‎6‎/‎17‎/‎2015‎ ‎3‎:‎21‎:‎39‎ ‎PM".split(' ')[2].trim()
```

returns "PM" correctly, yet the comparison fails.

I tried all sorts of tricks including a custom split function, but to no avail.

Even after splitting the individual numeric string values, parseInt returns NaN.

Comment: Have you logged the values you're comparing? How about the `.length` of each? what version of IE are you using?

Comment: I debugged and watched values in Visual Studio. Length is correct. IE is 11.

Comment: Can you post what `JSON.stringify(the_string)` returns? You sure there isn't a hidden character in there somewhere? What about your `PM` string?

Comment: What is the encoding of your page?

Comment: Thanks for all the assistance. The string comes directly from new Date().toLocaleString(). Now I have started to work around this issue by storing the original Date object (which I had converted to LocaleString) and using that directly. It works now, but I am still wondering why this wouldn't work. Will try the json stringify suggestion now.

Comment: Using `JSON.stringify` on the string has no effect. The problem characters in the string are not escaped by that, so they remain in the string and are still invisible when printed.

Comment: you can use `.replace()` as posted below to remove all unwanted/hidden characters

Comment: Yes the replace did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is a problem of characters:

Your ‎`‎PM`

```
"‎‎PM".length //returns 4
^^^^ -> String.fromCharCode(8206, 8206, 80, 77)
```

My `PM`

```
"PM".length //returns 2
^^^^ -> String.fromCharCode(80, 77)
```

**Solution:** replace unwanted characters.

```js
"‎6‎/‎17‎/‎2015‎ ‎3‎:‎21‎:‎39‎ ‎PM".replace(/[^\d\w/: ]+/gi,"").split(' ')[2].trim() == "PM" //true!
```

Comment: If you copy his "PM" into a text editor and keep pushing backspace, you'll see there is an extra character in his.

Comment: Thanks! The replace did it!

Comment: @lrsjng it is not necessary, it is obvious that should replace unwanted characters, I was even thinking of replacing the utf8 unusual characters like .replace(/[^\u0000-\u007F]+/gi,"")

Answer (score 1):

As a brute force method you can remove all undesired characters by inserting `.replace(/[^\d\w:/ ]/g, '')`

```
"‎6‎/‎17‎/‎2015‎ ‎3‎:‎21‎:‎39‎ ‎PM".replace(/[^\d\w:/ ]/g, '').split(' ')[2].trim()
```

Comment: I'm sorry I saw your response late. I've marked the correct answer below which is equivalent to yours.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your `PM`.

I copied your PM into a text editor and opened it in a Hex editor. Here is the output:

[image]

You'll notice some strange characters right before `PM`.

Here is what it would look like normally:

[image]

Searching for the `E2 80 8E` characters in Google provides a link to [this](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm) page, which shows it is the Unicode character for Left-To-Right Mark

Answer (score 0):

Taking your code and printing out the character codes, you get:

```
  34  8206     54   8206    47   8206    49     55
8206    47   8206     50    48     49    53   8206
  32  8206     51   8206    58   8206    50     49
8206    58   8206     51    57   8206    32   8206
  80    77     34     46   115    112   108    105
 116    40     39     32    39     41    91     50
  93    46    116    114   105    109    40     41
  32    61     61     32    34     80    77     34
```

Those `8206` characters in there is the [`left-to-right mark` character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark) that got into your code, plobably from copying the string from somewhere. The mark is a control character that is invisible when printed, it only affects how adjacent characters are displayed.

It's specifically the last one of those that is causing your problem. The last string from splitting the string isn't `"PM"` but `"\u200EPM"`. When you compare that to the string `"PM"`, they are not equal.

If you type in the code instead of copy-pasting it, it works just as expected.